# Browserify assign relative paths to modules instead of absolute paths

Tags: javascript, browserify

Given this file tree:

```
src
  - main.js
  ui
    - foo.js
    - bar.js
```

This command generates modules where identifiers have been set to absolute module paths:

`browserify ./src/**/*.js -o ./dist/bundle.js --full-paths`

Resulting module id:

`"/Users/rikschennink/.../src/ui/foo.js"`

Is there a way to make those module paths relative? If I omit the `--full-paths` command I'm left with indexes as module identifiers so that's not working.

I want to bundle all modules but still be able to reference them with require by path like this.

`var module = require('/ui/foo');`

I'm aware I can alias the modules but that would require aliasing every single module manually which is not really a workable solution.

---

I went with a JavaScript function that replaces absolute paths in the output stream. You can find it here:
https://github.com/rikschennink/conditioner-boilerplate-browserify/blob/master/browserify.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply use `sed` to fix the stuff for me

```
browserify -r ./src/ui/bar -r ./src/main ./src/**/*.js --full-paths | sed "s|$PWD/src||g" > ./dist/bundle.js
```

Then last line generated is

```
},{}]},{},["/main.js","/ui/bar.js","/ui/ui.js"]);
```

Just as you wanted

Comment: Will that work on both windows and osx? As in, can I run that as an entry in package.json?

Comment: @Rik, for windows it will work when you run it in Git bash or any other unix emulating terminal for windows

Comment: alright, great!This was not exactly what I was looking for but indeed it works, it sent in me in the right direction. Wrote a little script that I can add to the browserify.js config (will add to question in a minute as it might be useful for others). Thanks!

Comment: Okie cool :-). If you had said no to this, my next suggestion would have been to go for a script and do this modification using js code. Make it independent of availability of `$PWD` and `sed`. That makes it work across OS